# Element is no longer attached to the DOM - for a Button

Tags: selenium, webdriver

**Issue** - Getting 'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'

**Approach** - 
1. Check if the element is displayed on the webpage
2. Trying to click the element

**Code** -

```
System.out.println("boolean value of Confirm order is" +driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder")).isDisplayed());
if (driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder")).isDisplayed() == true) {          driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder")).sendKeys("{Enter}");
//actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("confirmOrder"))).build().perform();
//actions.click().perform();
System.out.println("button clicked");
}
```

**Output**
boolean value of Confirm order istrue
button clicked

Tried couple of approaches but none seems to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also tried:-{driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='confirmOrder' and @class='confirmOrder']")).click();}

Comment: what line raises 'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'?

Comment: @alexander-petrovich - I am not getting the error with this approach below but neither the button is getting clicked:-- 'System.out.println("Boolean value of button searched through xpath is" +driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='confirmOrder' and @class='btn btnPrimary']")).isDisplayed());'
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='confirmOrder' and @class='btn btnPrimary']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using implicit or explicit waits, [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174515/element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom) for more info,a very neat explanation is provided on this **issue**...

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, certain web elements such as button doesn’t gets clicked using the below line of code:-
driver.findElement(By.id("ButtonID")).click();

Tried using XPath as well but that didn’t used to work always.

Following is the thread that list down the issue with Windows 7: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6112

This is the workaround:-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ButtonID"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```