# Problems with Protractor and sendingKeys

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, protractor, chai

So I am trying to use Protractor to test a non-angular application (using Mocha).  I have this code:

```
var page = createAccountPage.create('/noname');

page.typeFirstNameInput('jane');
page.typeLastNameInput('doe');
page.typePasswordInput('password');
page.clickAgreedToTermsInput();
page.clickCreateAccountButton();

page.redirectToCreateProfilePage();
```

Note that the `type*()` are all pretty much the same:

```
createAccountPage.typeFirstNameInput = function(value) {
  $(selector).sendKeys(value);
};
```

This basically opens the browsers and should fill in the form fills and then clicks a button that redirect the page.  The issue that I am running into is that it fills out all the form inputs except the first name.  If I do this:

```
var page = createAccountPage.create('/noname');

page.typeFirstNameInput('jane');
page.typeFirstNameInput('jane');
page.typeLastNameInput('doe');
page.typePasswordInput('password');
page.clickAgreedToTermsInput();
page.clickCreateAccountButton();

page.redirectToCreateProfilePage();
```

Then it does fill out the first name however I get the error:

```
StaleElementReferenceError: Element is no longer attached to the DOM
```

The only reason I can see this happening is that the form is fill out correctly now and clicking the button redirects the pages and for whatever reason, the first `page.typeFirstNameInput('jane');` is being executed last (which would also explain when when I have it there once, the first name is filled out).

Is there any reason why the first action `page.typeFirstNameInput('jane');` would be executed last?

Comment: can you mention `typeFirstNameInput` function body above? This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174515/element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom

Comment: Added it, all the type* methods are the same.